# Android : Nullpointer issue

Tags: android

My Nullpointer expection has me stumped. I am getting nullpointer exception at FindViewByID. Here is my piece of code

```
public class numberActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.number);

}    

ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
public void numberClick(View v) {   
    switch(v.getId()){
            case R.drawable.numberone:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
                break;

            case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
                break;

        }

}
```

}

My number.xml is here

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/numberImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/numberone" 
    android:onClick="numberClick" />
```

Very simple code i think, but the null pointer exception is frustrating me since last night. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. It worked after i moved ImageView to the OnCreate Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
```

This line has to be in the onCreate method.
Like this

```
  public class numberActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView portrait;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.number);
//This element will be found once your contentview is set
        portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);

    }    


    public void numberClick(View v) {   
        switch(v.getId()){
                case R.drawable.numberone:
                    portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
                    break;

                case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                    portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
                    break;

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, obtain the `ImageView` in the onCreate method.
 The reason you are getting a null pointer exception is that you cannot `initialize` an object outside any function in java. The initializations have to be made in a function, in this case on `onCreate()`.
Anything non-static declared outside a `function` or `constructors` is never initialized. It is just there. To start using it, initialize it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this line.

```
 ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
```

Move the 'portrait' variable to class member and intialize it in onCreate() after setContentView() this will solve your problem.

or change your code like this

```
public class numberActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.number);

} 



  public void numberClick(View v) {   
     switch(v.getId()){
        case R.drawable.numberone:
            ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
            break;

        case R.drawable.numbertwo:
            ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
            break;

    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public class numberActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.number);


ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
}    

public void numberClick(View v) {   
    switch(v.getId()){
            case R.drawable.numberone:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numbertwo);
                break;

            case R.drawable.numbertwo:
                portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.numberthree);
                break;

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this

```
 ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberImage);
```

In onCreate method..